.htaccess If directive not working when accessing php files directly (only when accessing directories)
I have some code to do persistent authentication with .htaccess, which works, but only when accessing directories or sub-directories, e.g. / works but /index.php doesn't. Here is some simplified code which has the same issue:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUIRE_AUTH:1]
<If "%{ENV:REQUIRE_AUTH} == 1">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Area"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</If>

Trying to debug this I can confirm the REQUIRE_AUTH variable is set, but the If directive does not seem to be able to see its value so it doesn't execute.
Setting a header depending if REQUIRE_AUTH is set works, but the If won't execute unless I change the condition to == ''

One very unintuitive thing about Apache configuration is that it's not processed in the order written - each module runs in turn, and can only see the result of previous modules.
This is mentioned on the manual page describing expressions:

When environment variables are looked up within an <If> condition, it's important to consider how extremely early in request processing that this resolution occurs. As a guideline, any directive defined outside of virtual host context (directory, location, htaccess) is not likely to have yet had a chance to execute. SetEnvIf in virtual host scope is one directive that runs prior to this resolution

And further elaborated on the section about merging configuration sections:

At runtime, the core of httpd iterates over the defined configuration sections in the order described above to determine which ones apply to the current request. When the first section matches, it is considered the current configuration for this request. If a subsequent section matches too, then each module with a directive in either of the sections is given a chance to merge its configuration between the two sections. The result is a third configuration, and the process goes on until all the configuration sections are evaluated.
After the above step, the "real" processing of the HTTP request begins: each module has a chance to run and perform whatever tasks they like. They can retrieve their own final merged configuration from the core of the httpd to determine how they should act.

So what is happening is that at the time Apache tests the expression for the <If> block, mod_rewrite hasn't yet run, so the environment variable is not set.
As mentioned in the first quote, a SetEnvIf directive will probably be evaluated early enough and give you the desired result.

I have tried that as well to no avail, the same happens (works with /, not with /index.php)
